# Extjs Combo box - Picker doesn't change

Tags: extjs

I have this code:

```
var comboStore = new Ext.data.Store({
proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : '../cxf/rest/CustomerService/getGroups'
}),
reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    fields : [ 'id', 'name' ]
}), 
autoLoad : true
});
```

and

```
var groupsCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
name : 'GroupsCombo',
fieldLabel : 'Groups',
mode : 'local',
store : comboStore,
displayField : 'name',
triggerAction : 'all',
valueField : 'groupID',
selectOnFocus:true,
width : 130
});
```

When the page is loaded the values are populated successfully in the combo box.
However, when I'm trying to select a value from the combo, the first value is always selected. I'm not talking programatically here, but even on the browser the first value would be selected.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry :S

I don't know how I didn't notice this, but the the id in Json data store should be groupID istead of 'id'..

I changed this and it's working now.

Comment: add your answer and mark it as accepted so people with a similar issue can see how you solved it

Comment: I wanted to.. but there was some time limit to answer your own questiosn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry :S I don't know how I didn't notice this, but the the id in Json data store should be groupID istead of 'id'.. I changed this and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a JsonStore? Try doing something like this:

```
var comboStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
       id: 'JsonStore',
       idProperty: 'id',
       autoLoad: true,
       idProperty: 'id',
       root: <root of your JSON>,
       fields: [ 'id', 'name' ],
       proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
           api: {
               read: '../cxf/rest/CustomerService/getGroups',
           }
       })
   });
```

Then use that is the Store for the ComboBox. A JsonStore automatically creates a JsonReader, which I think is where the conflict in your code is.